# POST Request with strange referer

Tags: post, iis, referrer

I have a series of POST requests to my site with this string as REFERER

Referer: 'http://www.google.com/?q=MZDBWGLKZ'

Can anyone tell me what it could be?
for now I blocked it but... is this a normal request? what kind? or are they attacks?

These are two example of log:

```
2021-10-19 ; 17:15:40 ; W3SVC3 ; OnPreprocHeaders ; 185.56.80.65 ;  ; www.un*****a.it ; Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1 ; POST ; / ; HTTP/1.1 ; 0 ; http://www.google.com/?q=WKULZ ; BLOCKED: 'http://www.google.com/?q=' not allowed in Referrer URL ; Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1 ; 
2021-10-19 ; 17:15:40 ; W3SVC3 ; OnPreprocHeaders ; 185.56.80.65 ;  ; www.un*****a.it ; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP) ; POST ; / ; HTTP/1.1 ; 0 ; http://www.google.com/?q=BPBRERZ ; BLOCKED: 'http://www.google.com/?q=' not allowed in Referrer URL ; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP) ;
```

Comment: For a public facing web site, you should expect `Referer` to be of any possible value. The actual attacks usually come from POST payloads, not such standard headers (unless the web server has a vulnerability there, but really rare).

Comment: Referer can also be added through url rewrite, you can check whether you added it in iis.

Comment: @samwu I have no rule in url rewrite about HTTP_REFERER